# Flutter, tabs and access single tab widget state

Tags: flutter, tabs, state

I have a tab that dynamically has n tabs content widgets. So there is widget page with tab header and one widget foreach tab content. Now I need to implement search in main tab which search in every tab content widget and if searched string is found change the current tab and highlight the string funded. To do this I need to access every tab content state from main tab page, I try to create a list of GlobalKeys, one for each tab content widget but only the first key have the state of first tab content widget, other keys have all state members not initialized. I don't know why.

There is a way to solve this or it is better to avoid one widget for each tab content and put all in main tab page?
Thank you

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I added some code below, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here the code. I specify that the n tabs are the same type of statefull widget but populated with different data.

Definition of list of global key of tabs:

```
List<GlobalObjectKey> tabKeys = List.empty(growable: true);
```

The following code build single tab page widget, the key is created and assigned to the ProgramDayWidget that is the statefull widged whose status I want to access:

```
Widget buildTabView(BuildContext context, Program p) {
programDayWidgets.clear();
List<Widget> tabs = [];

tabKeys.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < p.days.length; i++)
{
  var k = GlobalObjectKey("tab" + i.toString());
  tabKeys.add(k);

  var w = ProgramDayWidget(event: event, programDay: p.days[i], key: k);

  programDayWidgets.add(w);
  tabs.add(w);
}

return Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: TabBarView(
    children: tabs,
    controller: _tabController,
  ),
)};
```

tabKeys is cleared every time the tab is rebuild for SetState calls.
If I put a breakpoint on this function after a SetState tabKeys has 3 keys (correct like tabs) but only the first key has the currentState member initialized for the first tab, in others two keys currentStale, like other members of the key, is null.

Thank you